# How to implement CarouselPage in MAUI

Tags: maui

I have implemented "mock up" pages in my Xamarin.Forms application using `CarouselPage` like below. I have 4 child pages and on each page I will show my app's core feature using an image and it will auto swipe to next page after 5 seconds.

**MockUpHomePage.xaml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CarouselPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
    BackgroundColor="#e6e6e6"
    x:Class="MyProjectName.Views.MockUp.MockUpHomePage">
        
</CarouselPage>
```

**MockUpHomePage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MockUpHomePage : CarouselPage
{
    bool isStart = true;
    public MockUpHomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Children.Add(new MockUp1());
        this.Children.Add(new MockUp2());
        this.Children.Add(new MockUp3());
        this.Children.Add(new MockUp4());

        Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), () =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                int index = Children.IndexOf(CurrentPage);
                if (index == 0)
                {
                    CurrentPage = Children[1];
                }
                else if (index == 1)
                {
                    CurrentPage = Children[2];
                }
                else if (index == 2)
                {
                    CurrentPage = Children[3];
                }
                else if (index == 3)
                {
                    CurrentPage = Children[0];
                }
            });
            return isStart; // runs again, or false to stop
        });
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        try
        {
            isStart = false;
            base.OnDisappearing();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**MockUp1.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<renderer:CustomPage  
    xmlns:renderer="clr-namespace:CallerBee.Renderer"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    BackgroundColor="#e6e6e6"
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
    x:Class="MyProject.Views.MockUp.MockUp1">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="#e6e6e6">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="92*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackLayout
                Grid.Row="0"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Image 
                    Margin="20,5,5,5"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Source="ic_light_logo_xx.png">
                    <Image.HeightRequest>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                            <OnIdiom.Phone>30</OnIdiom.Phone>
                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>45</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>30</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                        </OnIdiom>
                    </Image.HeightRequest>
                </Image>

                <StackLayout 
                    Margin="5,5,25,5"
                    Padding="5"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                    <Label 
                        Text="Login"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        FontAttributes="Bold" >
                        <Label.FontSize>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                <OnIdiom.Phone>18</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>27</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>18</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                            </OnIdiom>
                        </Label.FontSize>
                    </Label>

                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            Tapped="ShowLoginPage"
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                        </TapGestureRecognizer>
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>

            <Image
                x:Name="mockup1_image"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="0,0,0,10"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</renderer:CustomPage>
```

**MockUp1.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MockUp1 : CustomPage
{
    public MockUp1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
        {
            mockup1_image.Source = "ic_mockup1_xx.jpg";
        }
        else if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
        {
            mockup1_image.Source = "ic_mockup1_tablet_xx.jpg";
        }
    }

    private async void ShowLoginPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

When I migrated this xamarin forms app to MAUI, I found `CarouselView` supersedes the `CarouselPage`. I tried using `CarouselView` to implement the same feature, but I didn't get a clear idea about the implementation. Is `CarouselView` takes children like `CarouselPage`? Do I need to implement it on a single page?

Why MAUI deprecated the `CarouselPage`, it is a very useful feature.

Comment: CarouselView works like CarouselPage, except that it's child controls are Views, not Pages

Comment: `Why MAUI deprecated the CarouselPage, it is a very useful feature.` - So that you use CarouselView instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `MockUpDataTemplateSelector` like below:

```
public class MockUpDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate MockUp1 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate MockUp2 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate MockUp3 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate MockUp4 { get; set; }
    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        switch (((MockUp)item).Index)
        {
            case 1: return MockUp1;
            case 2: return MockUp2;
            case 3: return MockUp3;
            case 4: return MockUp4;
            default: return MockUp1;
        }
    }
}

public class MockUp
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

Create `MockUp1, MockUp2, MockUp3 and MockUp4` as `ContentView`.

**MockUp1.xaml**

```
<ContentView 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="AppName.Views.MockUp.MockUp1">
    
    <Grid BackgroundColor="#e6e6e6">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="92*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout
            Grid.Row="0"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image
                Margin="20,5,5,5"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Source="ic_light_logo_xx.png">
                <Image.HeightRequest>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                        <OnIdiom.Phone>30</OnIdiom.Phone>
                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>45</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>30</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                    </OnIdiom>
                </Image.HeightRequest>
            </Image>

            <StackLayout
                Margin="5,5,25,5"
                Padding="5"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <Label
                    Text="Login"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    FontAttributes="Bold" >
                    <Label.FontSize>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                            <OnIdiom.Phone>18</OnIdiom.Phone>
                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>27</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>18</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                        </OnIdiom>
                    </Label.FontSize>
                </Label>
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="ShowLoginPage"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

        <Image
            x:Name="mockup1_image"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="0,0,0,10"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

**MockUp1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MockUp1 : ContentView
{
    public MockUp1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (DeviceInfo.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Phone)
        {
            mockup1_image.Source = "ic_mockup1_xx.jpg";
        }
        else if (DeviceInfo.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Tablet)
        {
            mockup1_image.Source = "ic_mockup1_tablet_xx.jpg";
        }
    }

    private async void ShowLoginPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Then create `MockUpHomePage` as a `ContentPage`.

**MockUpHomePage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <toolkit:StatusBarBehavior StatusBarColor="#e6e6e6" StatusBarStyle="DarkContent" />
</ContentPage.Behaviors>

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MockUp1">
        <control:MockUp1/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="MockUp2">
        <control:MockUp2/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MockUp3">
        <control:MockUp3/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="MockUp4">
        <control:MockUp4/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <control:MockUpDataTemplateSelector 
        x:Key="MockUpSelector"
        MockUp1="{StaticResource MockUp1}"
        MockUp2="{StaticResource MockUp2}"
        MockUp3="{StaticResource MockUp3}"
        MockUp4="{StaticResource MockUp4}"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<CarouselView 
    x:Name="mycarsoel"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MockUps}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MockUpSelector}" />
```

**MockUpHomePage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MockUpHomePage : ContentPage
{
    public List<MockUp> MockUps { get; set; }
    bool isStart = true;
    public MockUpHomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MockUps = new List<MockUp>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            MockUp up = new MockUp() { Index = i };
            MockUps.Add(up);
        }
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), () =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                MockUp currentMockUp = mycarsoel.CurrentItem as MockUp;
                if (currentMockUp.Index == 1)
                {
                    mycarsoel.CurrentItem = MockUps[1];
                }
                else if (currentMockUp.Index == 2)
                {
                    mycarsoel.CurrentItem = MockUps[2];
                }
                else if (currentMockUp.Index == 3)
                {
                    mycarsoel.CurrentItem = MockUps[3];
                }
                else if (currentMockUp.Index == 4)
                {
                    mycarsoel.CurrentItem = MockUps[0];
                }
            });
            return isStart; // runs again, or false to stop
        });
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        try
        {
            isStart = false;
            base.OnDisappearing();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + ex);
        }
    }
}
```